# Getting stacktrace for exceptions in Spring @Transactional method

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

Recently had a case where @Transactional method completed without reporting any problems but with no data written to DB, so rollback happened at some point. Took me lot of time to find a line where NullPointerException was thrown. Because there was no stacktrace or error logs to indicate a problem, it just finished silently.

So is there a way to get full trace after exception occurred in transaction?

Tried setting log level for `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor = trace` but only thing I got is `Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.NullPointerException` line, which although reporting what was the problem doesn't show where exactly it happened.

Comment: So where was that NPE? In Spring or your bussiness logic? IMHO you are swallowing exception at some point.

Comment: Agree with Antoniossss about swallowing the exception... Could you post the method's code?

Comment: NPE is in business logic in method called from @Transactional method, but there is lot of code. I'm not swallowing it, because if wrap everything inside @Transactional method with `try{} catch(Exception e) {}` it gets caught.

Answer (score 0):

If you want transaction to get rolled back in case of exception . Please through some child exception of Exception class . Please update you annotation as follows.
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)

Comment: Please refer url : https://dzone.com/articles/spring-transactional-amp-exceptions